# How to include HtmlUnit in a Kotlin project

Tags: java-7, htmlunit, kotlin

I'm trying to use [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) in a Kotlin project but I get the following error when I compile:

```
Error:Kotlin: Supertypes of the following classes cannot be resolved. Please make sure you have the required dependencies in the classpath:
    class com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.DomElement, unresolved supertypes: ElementTraversal
```

This is because [ElementTraversal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/ElementTraversal.html?is-external=true) is a java 7 feature. How can I solve this?

Comment: You don't indicate how you compile, and what JDK you are using to compile.  And are you compiling in an IDE (which?), or build system (which?)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `org.w3c.dom.ElementTraversal` is part of [`xml-apis`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/xml-apis/xml-apis) which is a dependency of [`xerces:xercesImpl`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/xerces/xercesImpl). The `xerces:xercesImpl` is in turn a dependency of [`htmlunit`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.htmlunit/htmlunit).

Make sure to add the transitive dependencies of [`htmlunit`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.htmlunit/htmlunit) to your project.

With gradle all that is needed is:

```
compile 'net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit:2.22'
```

Comment: Yeah, I have that in my maven as `<dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.htmlunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>htmlunit</artifactId>
            <version>2.22</version>
        </dependency>`

Comment: @Johnny take a look at your [`dependency:tree`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html)

Comment: Fixed by adding `<dependency>
            <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.01</version>
        </dependency>`, which is strange as it's a dependency of HtmlUnit.